# How can I create a column in one DataFrame containing the count of matches in another DataFrame's column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames. The first one, `df1`, contains a column of file paths and a column of lists containing what users have read access to these file paths. The second DataFrame, `df2`, contains a list of all possible users. I've created an example below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['path'] = ['C:/pathA', 'C:/pathB', 'C:/pathC', 'C:/pathD']
df1['read'] = [['userA', 'userC', 'userD'], 
               ['userA', 'userB'], 
               ['userB', 'userD'], 
               ['userA', 'userB', 'userC', 'userD']]
print(df1)

       path                          read
0  C:/pathA         [userA, userC, userD]
1  C:/pathB                [userA, userB]
2  C:/pathC                [userB, userD]
3  C:/pathD  [userA, userB, userC, userD]
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=['userA', 'userB', 'userC', 'userD'], columns=['user'])
print(df2)

    user
0  userA
1  userB
2  userC
3  userD
```

The end goal is to create a new column `df2['read_count']`, which should take each user string from `df2['user']` and find the total number of matches in the column `df1['read']`.

The expected output would be exactly that - a count of matches of each user string in the column of lists in `df1['read']`. Here is what I am expecting based on the example:

```
df2

    user  read_count
0  userA           3
1  userB           3
2  userC           2
3  userD           3
```

I tried putting something together using another question and list comprehension, but no luck. Here is what I currently have:

```
df2['read_count'] = [sum(all(val in cell for val in row)
                     for cell in df1['read'])
                     for row in df2['user']]
print(df2)

    user  read_count
0  userA           0
1  userB           0
2  userC           0
3  userD           0
```

What is wrong with the code I currently have? I've tried actually following through the loops but it all seemed right, but it seems like my code can't detect the matches I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df2.merge(df1['read'].explode().value_counts(),
          left_on='user', right_index=True)
```

Or, if you really need to use a different kind of aggregation that depends on "path":

```
df2.merge(df1.explode('read').groupby('read')['path'].count(),
          left_on='user', right_index=True)
```

output:

```
    user  path
0  userA     3
1  userB     3
2  userC     2
3  userD     3
```

Without `df2`:

```
df1['read'].explode().value_counts().reset_index()

# or
# df1.explode('read').groupby('read', as_index=False)['path'].count()
```

output:

```
   index  path
0  userA     3
1  userB     3
2  userC     2
3  userD     3
```

Comment: Solution worked for me! I'm curious, in what specific case would I need to use the second solution vs. the first one? Both of them worked for my problem.

Comment: For example if you have NaN in "path" and do not want to count them

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `np.hstack` to flatten the lists then count the unique values using `Counter` and `map` the counts back to `df2`

```
from collections import Counter
  
df2['count'] = df2['user'].map(Counter(np.hstack(df1.read)))
```

Result

```
    user  count
0  userA      3
1  userB      3
2  userC      2
3  userD      3
```